# Lubuntu 13.10 missing Try without installation option

Tags: installation, lubuntu, live-cd, livedvd

I just created a Lubuntu 13.10 LiveDVD via UNetbootin on my Ubuntu 13.04 system, in order to be able to use Lubuntu on an old work computer that runs slowly on Windows XP (a Dell Optiplex GOX 270, in case that makes a difference). I've gotten to the boot menu and my options are to Install Lubuntu (which I'm not authorized to do), check disc for defects, Test memory, Boot from first hard disk, and Rescue a broken system. Should I be using one of those options, or might I be missing something that ought to be there?

I cannot use a LiveUSB. I tried, but the computer doesn't recognize the USB as an option for booting up. It's a pretty old computer-- it has a 3.5" floppy drive, which is actually what I'm using so that I can up-convert our old files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a "try without installing" option, though it seems that this would have been a problem with the live image you created, not your computer.

As far as trying a live USB, which is usually more convenient, it's likely that your old computer doesn't support booting from USB because the BIOS is old. I once had this problem and solved it by updating the BIOS to the most recent version.

Here's an image of what the unetbootin disk options should look like (is this the menu you're referring to?):
[image]

Comment: Since I am not authorized to update the BIOS (and the computer isn't attached to the internet anyway), what should I do to fix or replace the live image? I downloaded it from lubuntu.net. Is there another source I should consider?

Comment: I've added an image of what the unetbootin options should be (I'm assuming this is the menu you're missing things from). If you don't have the options you want here, I would try making a new disk. And yes, the lubuntu site is the reliable source for the iso image.